# jpa OneToMany & ManyToOne

Tags: jpa

i have a oneToMany and ManyToOne mapping in my models:

class User

```
@OneToMany (cascade = { CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Judgement> judgements;
```

class Judgement

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User judge;
```

and in DB, i have to tables as Users and Judgements, when i tried to run my code, it showed error as:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "users_judgements" does not exist
```

does that mean i have to create the table users_judgements by hand, jpa cannot automatically create the relationship for me? RoR can do it...Thanks.

Comment: which orm framework you are using to tie jpa, i mean are you using hibernate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a foreign key from USER table, user_id, in JUDGMENT table then there is no need to have another table. That will be the @JoinColumn(name = "user_id").

See if you are missing something; I can not see any "**mappedBy**" attribute, which will be "user" in your case.

Please take a look at this article; page 4 that the link will take you, give details about one-to-many relationship. It will be worth reading the whole article.

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-01-2008/jw-01-jpa2.html?page=4

Also, the part 1 of the same tutorial is good for basics;

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-01-2008/jw-01-jpa1.html

Comment: @user468587 It will be helpful for many, if you could post your resolved mappings here.