# JPA One to Many Relation in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa

I have a one to many relationship (profile to message). I tried to save a message owned by a certain user/profile. What wrong with the code below?

```
public Message createMessage(Message msg, String recepient) {
    EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
    UserAccess access = new UserAccess();
    Profile user = access.searchUser(recepient);
    msg.setUser(user);

    em.getTransaction().begin();

    em.persist(msg);

    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
    return msg;
}
```

search user method

```
public Profile searchUser(String displayName){
    EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
    Profile user;
    try{
        Query q = em.createNamedQuery("Profile.searchByDisplayName");
        q.setParameter("displayName", displayName);
        user = (Profile) q.getSingleResult();
    } catch(javax.persistence.NoResultException e){
        user = null;
    }
    em.close();
    return user;
}
```

I encountered the error below:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Primary key for object of type Profile is null.
```

Comment: And the object returned from your named query is in what object state? Or is it a null object? Obviously the log tells you what is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can it be because you do not have an "Id", a primary key, defined in your Profile Entity? Or is not set to any value when you created the specific profile?

Also, check if the relationships are defined properly between the Profile and Message entities.

[jpa OneToMany & ManyToOne](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491532/jpa-onetomany-manytoone/10497312#10497312)

Comment: @JR Galia: Tiny request, it will help others if you briefly tell here that what the issue was and how you resolved it.